# WatchOS sendMessage sent only when watch app come back to front

Tags: ios, watchos-2, sendmessage

I have a new problem I never met before. 
I didn't change my app code since Friday, and I have different behavior.

When my app execute a sendMessage, it doesn't works immediately. The message is sent only when the app come back in front.

I use a lot of sendMessage and it worked perfectly since I started my app, several weeks ago.

For information, I just updated my Watch to Watch OS 2.2 this weekend.

Note I have this problem only with my watch, it works fine on the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I just finished first apple watch connectivity app following [this](http://techotopia.com/index.php/A_watchOS_2_WatchConnectivity_Messaging_Tutorial) tutorial:

I received the message from sendMessage() immediately. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems really abnormal behavior very, I developed several apps with message passing, never encounter your own abnormal. It is not that you are sending very large messages or've set some particular condition?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
Nothing of these. The sendMessage works fine on the simulator but not on the real Watch.
I'll try again this afternoon, I hope it was just a temporary bug on the Watch.

Comment: test on the device to remove and replace the application of Apple Watch

Comment: I've already tried this.
But today i restarted both Watch and iPhone and it works fine. 
Thanks.

Comment: as soon as I can I try to postarti an example today I travel without mac